# Store User Credentials on Appharbor

Tags: appharbor

I need to store user credentials in my app. I can store and retrieve the password with protectdata. But as soon as I push a new revision of my app I loose the credentials. It seems like appharbor cleans the ProtectedData Store.

Is this behavior on purpose? Is there a better way to store user credentials on appharbor. OAuth is not an options since it's a ftp account.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to the local instance file system are not persisted across deploys on AppHarbor, so you'll have to store the data someplace else. We generally recommend using Amazon S3. You can use `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect()` from the same API to encrypt data written there. Here's some sample code: [protect bytes data .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250360/protect-bytes-data-net)

I'm not super familiar with this API, but you might get into trouble if you app us running on multiple AppHarbor instances using different user accounts.

Comment: That's right. Would definitely be a problem since I am using the CurrentUser to protect the data.

Comment: Consider using this, then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681493/leveraging-asp-net-machinekey-for-encrypting-my-own-data/7824489#7824489